# How to call Queueable apex method from Visualforce Page commandButton?

Tags: apex, visualforce, trigger, action, queueable-apex

Right now if I call the action button **without Queueable Apex**, from all the parameters I get from the Visualforce page and then perform action on the backend, due to the Apex Triggers I always will get "Error: System.LimitException: Too many SOQL queries: 101".

So I'm trying to make my action call from a Queueable apex instead to avoid the SOQL queries limit exception.

So trying to perform this following code as below:

**Visualforce page:**

```
<apex:page controller="X_Controller" lightningStylesheets="true" extensions = "X_Queueable">
<td style="text-align:center;">
   <apex:commandButton value="Apply Adjustment" action="{!add_JobToQueue()}" reRender="showmsg" 
     onclick="this.disabled='true'; this.value='Generating...';return false;"/> 
</td>
</apex:page>
```

**X_Controller:**

```
public with sharing class X_Controller{

  public void ApplyChargeAdjustment(){
     //do something
  }
}
```

**X_Queueable :**

```
public with sharing class X_Queueable implements Queueable {
    
    public void execute(QueueableContext context) {
        //do something
    }

    public void add_JobToQueue(){
        ID jobID = System.enqueueJob(new X_Queueable());
    }
}
```

But when I save all the files I get this error :

> Unknown constructor 'X_Queueable.X_Queueable(X_Controller controller)'

Even when I try to create a constructor on the Queueable apex, the error wouldn't go away.

Help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define 2 constructors in your `X_Queueable.cls`.

```
public X_Queueable() {  
}
    
public X_Queueable(X_Controller controller){  
}
```

Aside from this, your visualforce markup also needs to change to include `<apex:form>` & a minor change in the `action` attribute.

```
<apex:page controller="X_Controller" lightningStylesheets="true" extensions = "X_Queueable">
    <apex:form>
        <td style="text-align:center;">
           <apex:commandButton value="Apply Adjustment" action="{!add_JobToQueue}" reRender="showmsg" 
             onclick="this.disabled='true'; this.value='Generating...';return false;"/> 
        </td>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Now there isn't any error when I save, but when I press the button on VF Page. I don't see any Apex jobs occuring. Any ideas?

Comment: I would think it's more of an issue with the `onClick` than anything else. Remove the `return false;` and you should get a job entry.